# Last character of a char array created from String's getchars() method changes to different character

Tags: java

I was working with getchars() method. Code didn't work as I expected, after debugging I found that last character added to char array from getchars() method gets changed. Last character value is changed to '\u0000' instead of 'w' from string passed. [Debugged Values attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIXPR.png)

```
public class TestDS {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String test = "{[]}qw";
        char[] chars = new char[test.length()];
        test.getChars(0, test.length() - 1, chars, 0);
        for (char temp : chars) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not copying the last character. The end index is an *index*, so it should point just past the end of the string. As it says in [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getChars(int,int,char[],int)):

> `srcEnd` - index **after** the last character in the string to copy.

*(my emphasis)*

So you don't want the `- 1` after `test.length()`. You're seeing the default value of `chars[chars.length-1]`, which is 0 (because arrays are initialized to all-bits-off values).

So:

```
test.getChars(0, test.length(), chars, 0);
// ---------------------------^
```

To illustrate:

```
{[]}qw
^     ^
|     |
|     +−−− srcEnd
+−−−−−−−−− srcBegin
```

Answer (score 1):

A char array is initialized with the value NULL character `\u0000`. The reason why `\u0000` is printed, is because you are only copying `test.length()-1` (exclusive stop) to `chars` and then printing all of `chars`, which has `\u0000` at index `test.length()-1`.

If you update your code to:

```
public class TestDS {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String test = "{[]}qw";
        char[] chars = new char[test.length()];
        test.getChars(0, test.length(), chars, 0);
        for (char temp : chars) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
{
[
]
}
q
w
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, messed that up. The whole array is initialized with the value `\u0000` though.

Comment: Right, because arrays are always initialized to all-bits-off. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are reducing the length while getting the characters.
test.getChars(0, test.length() - 1, chars, 0);

**Length method**:
Returns the length of this string.
The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.

**Change it to**:

test.getChars(0, test.length(), chars, 0);